# Sending a notification mail on uploading a document in DOCMAN

Tags: joomla1.5

HI ,

I am working on Joomla 1.5 . I am having Docman in my Joomla 1.5... Is it possible to set like "Sending mail to a person when someone uploads a document in docman from frontend".

Please give some suggestions .

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

[DOCman Notify | Email notifications](http://support.joomlatools.eu/tutorials/5-docman-notify.html)